# How to solve this integral in which matrices are involved?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, entropy

$$ -\int_{}^{} \frac {exp(\frac{1}{2}x^TP^{-1}x)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}log_2(\frac {exp(\frac{1}{2}x^TP^{-1}x)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}) dx$$ where x is a N dimensional Gaussian vector having variance as P and mean zero.
My approach is let  be given by $$x=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2}  \\
    \vdots\\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$ and P by \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & \sigma_{2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & \sigma_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
I am getting an integral like$$-\int_{}^{} \frac {exp(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{x_3^2}{\sigma_3^2}---+\frac{x_n^2}{\sigma_n^2}))}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}log_2(\frac {exp(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{x_3^2}{\sigma_3^2}---+\frac{x_n^2}{\sigma_n^2}))}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}) dx$$ but confused how to do this dx stuff when x is a vector. Am I doing it right?

The answer given is $$\frac{n}{2}log_2(2 \pi e)+ \frac {1}{2} log_2|P|$$